# How to speed up skimage morphology?

Tags: python, scikit-image

Right now Im trying to get rid of the long rectangular sides of a biological plate in my image. To do this I Do `img -= skimage.morphology.diameter_opening(omg,diameter_threshold=120)`
This takes around 8 seconds to do, which is extremely slow. Is there any python library built In c++ that is faster? Any recommendations for functions which speed this up?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing an image, or your code, or knowing if you are on a Raspberry Pi Zero or a supercomputer.

Comment: I'll also point out that diameter opening is an inherently expensive operation. The guts of it are written in Cython, which is compiled to C. (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/morphology/_max_tree.pyx) It should be reasonably fast. As hinted at by Mark, if you show us an image, there might be other operations that are faster to achieve what you want.